# Скрыть/Показать DIV по выбору RADIO

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть вот такая форма, при выборе к примеру "футболки" должен открыться "блок с футболками", а если выбрать "шорты", то "блок с футболками" должен исчезнуть и открыться "блок с шортами".

Вот такая простенькая задача на JS, но совсем не силен в нем, облазил уже кучу статей и натыкался только на одинокий DIV, а тут их множество.

Все к чему пришел это пример ниже, но тут есть 2 проблемы, если нажать на radio блок появляется, при переключении открывает еще один блок, а этот не исчезает и также если таких radio будет штук 15-20, то JS получится слишком большой.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь, за ранее спасибо!

```js
function Selected(a) {
  var label = a.value;
    if(label=="kurtki"){
       document.getElementById("kurtki").style.display='block';
    } 
    else if(label=="svitshot"){
       document.getElementById("svitshot").style.display='block';
    }
    else if(label=="futbolki"){
       document.getElementById("futbolki").style.display='block';
    }
    else if(label=="shtani"){
       document.getElementById("shtani").style.display='block';
    }
    else if(label=="short"){
       document.getElementById("short").style.display='block';
    }
}
```

```css
.deactive{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<input name="select2" value="kurtki" type="radio" onChange="Selected(this)">Куртки
<input name="select2" value="svitshot" type="radio" onChange="Selected(this)">Свитера
<input name="select2" value="futbolki" type="radio" onChange="Selected(this)">Футболки
<input name="select2" value="shtani" type="radio" onChange="Selected(this)">Штаны
<input name="select2" value="short" type="radio" onChange="Selected(this)">Шорты


<div id='kurtki' class="deactive">блок с куртками</div>
<div id='svitshot' class="deactive">блок с свитерами</div>
<div id='futbolki' class="deactive">блок с футболками</div>
<div id='shtani' class="deactive">блок со штанами</div>
<div id='short' class="deactive">блок с шортами</div>
```

Comment: Вам обязательно на чистом JS или на jQuery тоже сойдет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для блоков нужно добавить общий класс и можно сделать более универсально :

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[name=select2]').forEach(s => {
  s.addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.someClass').forEach(d => d.classList.add('deactive'));
    document.getElementById(this.value).classList.remove('deactive');
  });
});
```

```css
.deactive {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input name="select2" value="kurtki" type="radio">Куртки
<input name="select2" value="svitshot" type="radio">Свитера
<input name="select2" value="futbolki" type="radio">Футболки
<input name="select2" value="shtani" type="radio">Штаны
<input name="select2" value="short" type="radio">Шорты

<div id='kurtki' class="someClass deactive">блок с куртками</div>
<div id='svitshot' class="someClass deactive">блок с свитерами</div>
<div id='futbolki' class="someClass deactive">блок с футболками</div>
<div id='shtani' class="someClass deactive">блок со штанами</div>
<div id='short' class="someClass deactive">блок с шортами</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Самый простой вариант, создать функцию, в которой будут скрываться все блоки и вызывать в начале функции `Selected`, так все блоки будут скрыты всегда перед тем, как будет показан новый. Можно также тело из функции `hideAllBlock` перенести в функцию `Selected`.

```js
function hideAllBlock() {
  document.getElementById("short").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("shtani").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("futbolki").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("svitshot").style.display = 'none';
  document.getElementById("kurtki").style.display = 'none';
}

function Selected(a) {
  hideAllBlock();
  document.getElementById(a.value).style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.deactive {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input name="select2" value="kurtki" type="radio" onChange="Selected(this)">Куртки
<input name="select2" value="svitshot" type="radio" onChange="Selected(this)">Свитера
<input name="select2" value="futbolki" type="radio" onChange="Selected(this)">Футболки
<input name="select2" value="shtani" type="radio" onChange="Selected(this)">Штаны
<input name="select2" value="short" type="radio" onChange="Selected(this)">Шорты


<div id='kurtki' class="deactive">блок с куртками</div>
<div id='svitshot' class="deactive">блок с свитерами</div>
<div id='futbolki' class="deactive">блок с футболками</div>
<div id='shtani' class="deactive">блок со штанами</div>
<div id='short' class="deactive">блок с шортами</div>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById(a.value).style.display = 'block';`

Comment: @Igor, спасибо за предложенную правку, как-то не додумался до этого.